# placing jQuery dialog box above div

Tags: jquery, jquery-dialog

I am new to jQuery and I am having trouble while placing jQuery box above a div.
I have a div with a button in it and on click of the button, JQuery dialog box opens.
The problem is dialog box is appearing behind the div and i want to place it above the div.  
I have searched the solution and found that specifying zIndex may solve the problem. But 
i am using jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js and zIndex is not supported for the version.

Please suggest any possible solution.

```
$("#mydialog").dialog({
  resizable: false,
  modal: true,
  title: "title",
  buttons: {
    Ok: function() {
    $(this).dialog("close");
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery UI 1.10 the `zIndex` option is removed:

> Removed `zIndex` option
>
> Similar to the stack option, the zIndex option is unnecessary with a
>   proper stacking implementation. The z-index is defined in CSS and
>   stacking is now controlled by ensuring the focused dialog is the last
>   "stacking" element in its parent.

You will have to use `css` to set the dialog "on top", like this:

```
.ui-dialog { z-index: 1000 !important;}
```

You need the `!important` to override the default styling of the element.

The value specified for the `z-index` must set higher than the `div`.

This affects all your dialogs if you need to set it only for a dialog use the `dialogClass` property.

Answer (score 1):

Because The CSS z-index for the jQuery UI dialog is not high enough to always show above your content
All you have to do is override the z-index  for class (ui-dialog) in your css

```
.ui-dialog{z-index: 1000 !important;}
```

Comment: While your answer may address the issue, it's good to provide an explanation of what your code does. Code/markup alone is often not self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

Try using firebug or developer tools to get the id or class of the element in question then in you css, set it's z-index to be higher